# Resource scheduling logic

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I've to schedule few resource for booking. Below is my logic

Sample:

I've to schedule Delux(2) and Classic(1) room for a year. So I'm inserting 1095 records(730+365-a row for every day each resource).

Database:
 table(SID,SDATE,ROOMID,STATUS)

For the particular day, I'm checking the schedule count which has status as 'available' and allowing to book.

Is the logic correct one? or any other logic which reduce number of record insertion?(Note:resource count per day may vary)

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use START_DATE and END_DATE instead of the SDATE to store intervals?

For the particular day you can ask the same status for intervals where the day between the interval's START_DATE and END_DATE.

Even better to track only booked intervals all the rest are free. So all rooms are free except defined intervals for already booked ones.

Comment: I said resource count is not fixed one. It may vary per day. Example: for 29th 5rooms and 30th 7rooms. then how can i?

Comment: @StanislavL All emails on your site are broken and unaccessible (at least from mail.ru). Please update information on you site how to connect to you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly you have a variable resource pool that you receive somehow. Assuming this is in the form of room X of type T from date A to date B.
I would store this into a table "availability", so at any time you can have a view on overall availability per day. If you couple this with StanislavL answer you would have two tables one for available rooms and one for bookings:

```
availability(availability_id,room_id,date_from,date_to)
booking(booking_id,room_id,date_from,date_to)
room(room_id,type,name,address,..)
```

Number of available rooms per day is obtained by subtracting via NOT IN clause the booked rooms from the available ones. Also, when you need to book a room you can check in the availability table if this is actually possible.